# Problem in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC accessing wwwroot folder

Tags: excel, .net-7.0

I am working on a project in .NET 7 where I need to upload Excel data  to a database through the application (not direct import with SQL).

I have a problem accessing the `wwwroot` folder. Despite it being created and I can open the Excel file with File explorer, when I run my app, I get this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'C:\Users...\wwwroot\uploaded_doc\testImport.csv' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

It is happening on opening the connection.

I am using this OLEDB connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'
```

Can someone tell me what the problem could be? If someone knows how to resolve it, please let me know.

Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCgzG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `IWebHostEnvironment` to dynamically get the path to `wwwroot`. `Inject IWebHostEnvironment` into your controller or service and use it

```
string webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;
string filePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "uploaded_doc", "testImport.csv");
```

Comment: Hi @Suryateja, thank you for the replay but i have that part already implemented

Comment: `public string DocUpload(IFormFile fromFile)
{
      string uploadPath = env.WebRootPath;
            string dest_path = Path.Combine(uploadPath, "uploaded_doc");
            if(!Directory.Exists(dest_path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dest_path);
            }
            string sourceFile = Path.GetFileName(fromFile.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(dest_path, sourceFile);
            using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create))
            {
                fromFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
  }
   return path;
 }`